# Get and save all id start with using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have structure like this

```
<div id-"form-input">
   <div id="form1"></div>
   <div id="form2"></div>
   <div id="form3"></div>
   <div id="form4"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get a number of form like `1`, `2`, ... `n`. I try using this code just to get all `id`.

```
var num = new Array();
var elems = $('div[id^=form]');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
   alert(elems[i]);
   num.push(elems[i]);
}
alert(num);
```

But it returns `[object HTMLdivElement]`. What is wrong? How can I get just the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()` method like following.

```js
var num = $('div[id^=form]').map(function() {
    var id = this.id.split('form')[1];
    if(!isNaN(id))
        return +id; // + to convert string to num
}).get();
alert(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id-"form-input">
   <div id="form1"></div>
   <div id="form2"></div>
   <div id="form3"></div>
   <div id="form4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the number, then

replace

```
num.push(elems[i]);
```

by

```
num.push(i+1);
```

If you want total id then as @satpal has suggested

```
num.push(elems[i].id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract number from id property so use

```
num.push(elems[i].id.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

instead of

```
num.push(elems[i]);
```

```js
var num = new Array();
var elems = $('#form-input div[id^=form]');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  num.push(elems[i].id.replace(/\D/g, ''));
}
console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-input">
  <div id="form1"></div>
  <div id="form2"></div>
  <div id="form3"></div>
  <div id="form4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to take the id's then use `map()`,

```
$('#form-input > div').map(function() {
       console.log(this.id);
});
```